# Analyzing post request

Tags: c++, qt, http, post

I'm trying to make post request using c++ Qt. 
The target site is  http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/advanced/ 

The site looks  so:
[image]

I inspected it with browser. 
And there is one strange thing for me - random number in header. 

So, I'm not sure whether I send data for post request correctly.

[image]

What have they done it for?
I make my request so (as browser does):

```
postdata.append("accept:*/*&");
postdata.append("accept-charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3&");
postdata.append("Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch&");
postdata.append("Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8&");
postdata.append("Connection:keep-alive&");
postdata.append("Content-Length:36&");
postdata.append("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded&");
postdata.append("Cookie:__utma=1.904416008.1352897318.1352905816.1352909441.3; __utmc=1; __utmz=1.1352897318.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __atuvc=7%7C46&");
postdata.append("Host:www.artlebedev.ru&");
postdata.append("Origin:http://www.artlebedev.ru&");
postdata.append("Referer:http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/advanced/&");
postdata.append("User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11&");
postdata.append("X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest&");
postdata.append("random:0.9632773566991091&"); // I have no idea about this number
postdata.append("Form Dataview URL encoded&");
postdata.append("csin:0&");
postdata.append("csout:0&");
postdata.append("text:fvddas&");
postdata.append("Decode:go");
```

I get webpage in answer. But that webpage doesn't contain decoded string. Only empty stings.
 It looks so:
[image]

This is my first attempt to make post request, please help me find a way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random value looks like some kind of [Cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) token to prevent people from doing what you are trying to do, but it is actually not being used. If I re-issue the request using Fiddler without any cookies or the random value, the request still succeeds.

In fact, this request also does:

```
POST http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/advanced/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.artlebedev.ru
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 33

csin=0&csout=0&text=foo&Decode=go
```

So there must be something wrong with your request, and I guess you shouldn't have just copypasted the request from an external viewer into code, but looked at what you are doing:

```
postdata.append("Form Dataview URL encoded&");
```

This is not an HTTP header. It's even nice of the server to not respond with a `400 Bad Request`. What should be in the place of that line is a single CRLF, to separate the headers from the entity ('request body').

It could prove useful if you output the contents of `postdata` just before you send it, to look if you can see something wrong.

Perhaps if you like the encoding translation that site can do (or whatever it is it does), you can ask the creators of the site if they have a publicly available API that you can address, or perhaps they'll even share some code or point you towards valuable resources to recreate such a conversion for yourself.

Comment: you opened my eyes, especially Fiddler is a super useful tool for understanding and looking how it works.